# How to access an index in a vector without segfaulting

Tags: c++, vector

I know this is simple, so I apologize in advance.

I am segfaulting when trying to access a vector by index.  For example...

```
vector<float> some_vec;
int i = 0;

for (some iterator loop here)
{
    //snip
    some_vec[i] = some_float;
    i++;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who can say? It depends on the actual code in `some iterator loop here` and `//snip`. Is the iterator range in the loop empty? Do you ever resize `some_vec`? When every answer you get is a guess, that's a good indication of a bad question...

Comment: www.debug-my-code-for-me.com/i-wont-show-you-it-though.html

Comment: What's wrong with you guys? This is an almost out-of-the-box compilable repro that will very likely lead to exactly the runtime error zebra describes, and can easily be answered. No need to downvote and/or close at all.

Comment: ¤ You just need to make sure that the `some_vec.size()` is greater than your index, i.e. that there really *is* a vector element at that index. As a novice you may benefit from writing `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]`, because the `at` does range checking and throws an exception if not OK, guaranteed. As a later professional you may sacrifice the guarantee for more practical (but not generally guaranteed) detection, and more readable source code. :-) Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After

```
std::vector<float> some_vec;
```

your vector is empty. You must not access any element in it then, because there isn't any.

If you want to put values into it, you need to append them to the vector using `push_back()`

```
for (some iterator loop here)
{
    //snip
    some_vec.push_back(some_float);
    i++;
}
```

Alternatively, if you know the size in advance, and if the construction of dummy values in the vector is cheap (as it is for `float` and other built-ins), you can `resize()` the vector in advance

```
some_vec.resize(42);
```

or create it with the right amount of elements

```
std::vector<float> some_vec(42);
```

Given either of the two above, you can then access elements `0..41` in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

call resize() function on your vector and then call push_back() to add elements. After this you can access elements using indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a problem elsewhere in code we can't see, but mostly likely given you've not called `resize()`, `push_back()` or `insert()` that `i` is outside of the vector. Use `some_vec.at(i) = some_float;` to check that `i` is within the valid range for the vector.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your `vector` is empty. Use `push_back(some_float)` to add elements to it.

Comment: Can I not initially assign at index 0 without pushing back?  I always thought you could, hm.

Comment: @zebra : Not if the vector is empty... Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: In order to do that, you need to know the number of items of your vector, and initialize it accordingly. For example, if you know that you are going to have ten items, declare your vector as `vector<float> some_vec(10);`

Comment: Okay then that is the answer.  I thought I remembered that if you try to assign one index above the current size, it would push it back for you.